# variably set ContentText of Dialog in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, dialog

For the user to confirm some changes I want a confirmation dialog to pop up, asking whether the selected Objects shall be deleted. This is variable of course.
The Text in the confirmation dialog should look like this:

```
Are you sure you want to delete   
Sample 1 from class 2  
Sample 3 from class 1  
Sample... and so on  
?
```

I have an ArrayList of Objects in which the information about samplename and class are stored.
What I got so far is:

```
ObservableList<Samples> samples = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
Alert info = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
info.setHeaderText("Confirm deletion");

if (samples.size() > 1) {
    List<String> strings= new ArrayList<>();
    samples.forEach(e ->
          strings.add(e.getSample().getSampleNr() +
                  " of class " +
                   e.getSample().getClass() +"\n")
            );
info.setContentText("Are you sure you want to delete \n" +
                    stridon't+ "?"
);
```

I dont know, maybe my thinking is blocked but I can't get it to work nicely.
It displays like this:

```
Are you sure you want to delete  
[Sample 1 of class 3  
, Sample 3 of class 1  
, ..and so on  
]?
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the [,] signs or maybe a nicer way o do this?
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can use is [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
String.join("delimiterHere", listHere);
```

```
info.setContentText("Are you sure you want to delete \n" + String.join("\n", strings) + "?");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is use a string builder

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Are you sure you want to delete \n");
samples.forEach(e ->
        stringBuilder.append(e.getSample().getSampleNr())
                .append(" of class ")
                .append(e.getSample().getClass())
                .append("\n"));

info.setContentText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Test Output:(Sample Data)

```
Are you sure you want to delete
Sample 0 of class Class 0
Sample 1 of class Class 1
```